# Integrate Facebook chat and SMS

Tags: sms, facebook

Is there a way to seamlessly integrate Facebook chat and SMS messaging? I am looking for a method that hides the detail of how a message was sent to a given contact or number as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new [Facebook Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca) released last week integrates SMS and Facebook Messages in the same app.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for one that hides the detail of how a message was sent to a given contact or number as well as possible.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. Do you mean you want it to not say whether it came through SMS vs. Facebook?

Anyway, there are numerous apps for this purpose. Some ideas:

1. [GO SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) plus the [Facebook Chat plug-in](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms.chat)
2. [IM+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.shapeservices.impluslite)
3. [Yuilop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yuilop)
4. [HeyWire](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mediafriends.chime)
5. [Pinger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pinger.textfree)